# IE11 is unable to render an SVG element and I can't figure out why

Tags: html, reactjs, internet-explorer

The error is:

```
     SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'contains' of undefined or null reference
```

The code looks like this (it's in a JSX file) and rendered in React:

```
        <div className={classes}>
            <svg className="someClassName" height={size} viewBox="50 50 50 50">
                <circle
                    className="loading"
                    cx="100"
                    cy="100"
                    fill="none"
                    r="20"
                    strokeMiterlimit="10"
                    strokeWidth={thickness}
                />
                <circle
                    className="path-startup"
                    cx="100"
                    cy="100"
                    fill="none"
                    r="20"
                    strokeMiterlimit="10"
                    strokeWidth={thickness}
                />
            </svg>
        </div>
```

I'm still stuck on what the error is.

Comment: theres a script error here. that has nothing to do with the svg

Comment: The error is a script error and I can't see how it is related with SVG. The code you provide can't reproduce the issue. Please provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test and see how to help. It's a React app then you can use some online code editor like [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) to show the code.